# JavaScript Code Analysis

Tags: javascript

Is there tool to find a methods which are not in scope?

```
function main(someValue)
{
    if(someValue)
    {
        function TestOne(){}
    }
    esle
    {
        function TestTwo(){}
        function TestThree(){}
    }
    //Call of function  
    TestTwo();
}
```

Here TestTwo() may be undefined, hence wanted to find such functions from huge code base.
If there is any tool which can detect then that will be quick help, application is ASP.net MVC and VS2010 is IDE.

Comment: http://eslint.org/ might help. Please understand that such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @Quentin: Different environments handle this case differently. Function declarations haven't been allowed inside blocks before ES5. In ES6 they are scoped to the block AFAIK. (I simply consider it this a bad example)

Comment: This is real example of bad code, worked till IE9, now on IE11 it breaks.

Comment: This may help: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-inner-declarations

Answer (score 1):

Whether TestTwo is defined or not just depend on your Javascript version. It doesn't depend on whether the if statement's true of false branch is followed.

In JavaScript before ES6, that is implementation dependent, some browsers will hoist that function declaration, so that it will be in scope. Others will throw an error.

In modern JavaScript it will never be defined, because function declarations have block scope, so the function is only in scope inside the else block.

The solution is to declare your functions unconditionally, but still call them as needed inside the if statement block:

```
function main(someValue)
{
    if(someValue)
    {
      ..
    }
    else
    {
      ..
    }
    //Call of function  
    TestTwo();

    function TestOne(){}
    function TestTwo(){}
    function TestThree(){}
}
```

Comment: *"In JavaScript before ES6 TestTwo will always be defined"* [See my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922695/javascript-code-analysis#comment61406986_36922695).

Comment: @FelixKling That's only true in strict mode.

Comment: Nope it's not... function declarations have never been allowed in blocks. Browser simply didn't comply with the spec in this regard. A block can only [contains statements](https://es5.github.io/#x12.1). But a `FunctionDeclaration` is not a `Statement`. ES6 introduced an appendix to "formalize" this behavior but only because browsers f*** this up: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-level-function-declarations-web-legacy-compatibility-semantics

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, I see. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Relevant quote from the ES6 spec: *"Prior to ECMAScript 2015, the ECMAScript specification did not define the occurrence of a FunctionDeclaration as an element of a Block statement’s StatementList. However, support for that form of FunctionDeclaration was an allowable extension and most browser-hosted ECMAScript implementations permitted them. Unfortunately, the semantics of such declarations differ among those implementations"* Although I have to confess that I wasn't aware that it was an "allowable extension" (and I'm not sure where / how it was allowed)

Comment: So on IE11 this pattern of code is breaking, is there a way to detect from large code base and fix it"?

Comment: ESLint VS.Net plugin and "no-inner-declarations" rule helped to find hundreds of places.
Thanks sharing root issues @Kling and Paulpro